# Rails / application.html.erb not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a ruby application and the application.html.erb is never loaded (looking at webrick output, I never get "Rendered CLASS/index.html.erb within layouts/application", but "Rendered CLASS/index.html.erb")

CLASS.html.erb never gets loaded either.

Only when explicitly specifying "render :file => 'layouts/application'" in the controller, application.html.erb is loaded.

Can anyone help?

Thanks a lot in advance

Sebastien

Answer (score 15):

Ensure that you're controller is inheriting from the ApplicationController.

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in your ApplicationController

```
layout :application
```

Now all of your controller use application like default layout.

Comment: class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  layout :application
end

Comment: In another application the ApplicationController looks like that:

Comment: class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base protect_from_forgery end

Comment: and the rendering is taking application.html.erb into account

Comment: This should never be needed as application.html.erb is the default unless you specifically override it.